# Cypher match nodes which have relationships to ALL nodes matching some criteria

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say I have a pizza menu where each type of pizza is represented as a node with label `Pizza`, and each topping is a node with label `Topping`.  To get all the pizza's with pepperoni I write the following query

```
MATCH (p:Pizza)-[:HAS]->(t:Topping{type : "pepperoni"}) return p.
```

Then say I have a set of users who can specify their favorite pizzas.

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:HAS_FAVORITE]->(p:Pizza).
```

What is the best way to find the users who like ALL the pizzas having pepperoni ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The following method compares the count of the user's favorites having pepperoni with the count of all pizzas with pepperoni.  It performs well because it matches using an index and relationship traversals to collect only user favorites having pepperoni.  The answer posted by cybersam is slow because it has to do a full scan of all favorites.

```
MATCH (p:Pizza)-[:HAS]->(t:Topping { type : "pepperoni" })
WITH COUNT(p) AS pCnt, COLLECT(p) AS pCol
UNWIND pCol as pPep
MATCH (u:User)-[:HAS_FAVORITE]->(pPep)
WITH u, COUNT(*) as fCnt, pCnt
WHERE fCnt = pCnt
RETURN u
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to find all distinct users who like ANY pizza(s) with pepperoni topping:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:HAS_FAVORITE]->(p:Pizza)-[:HAS]->(t:Topping {type : "pepperoni"})
RETURN DISTINCT u;
```

This is one way to find all distinct users who like ALL pizza(s) with pepperoni topping:

```
MATCH (p:Pizza)-[:HAS]->(t:Topping { type : "pepperoni" })
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
MATCH (u:User)-[:HAS_FAVORITE]->(q:Pizza)
WITH u, COLLECT(q) AS qs, ps
WHERE ALL (x IN ps WHERE x IN qs)
RETURN u;
```

Comment: The performance is slow because it scans, collects and evaluates every favorite.  I've posted a solution which only evaluates favorites having pepperoni.  An index is used for the initial match and relationship traversals are used to find the favorites.

Comment: Yes, my approach was just one way to do it, and was basically a brute force approach. I'm glad you found a more performant approach. It is quite similar to what occurred to me later, after I sent my answer.